# Flutter keyboard overflow

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm not sure if this is a bug or expected behavior but I do experience some problems with the keyboard and text fields widgets. Namely, I have two text fields on the screen and when I press one of them the keyboard opens with the white area (i believe its some kind of padding or something) which overlays my screen content and I can't see anymore the inputs... when I set `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` I am able to see the inputs but then the keyboard does not respect which text field I click and does not scroll content to that clicked text field and It again overlay it and cant see it. Also, I would expect default behavior of focused text field that when the text field is already focused and keyboard is open and then I click outside of the field somewhere on the screen the keyboard should close but it doesn't. Is this normal or its bugged currently?

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✗] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: What Flutter version? There was a change recently. You could try with `master` channel

Comment: Check if you have Expended or something similar, my guess its related to the UI that you were using, and I'm saying it because I had the same issue. In my case, flutter in debug mode were saying "overlap views" or something.